# 14.04 & Intel HD Graphics: undefined symbol: drm_intel_get_reset_stats

Tags: intel-graphics, 14.04

I can't get hardware acceleration to work with intel HD graphics 5000 (Core i5/Sandy Bridge). It was working properly on 13.10, but upgrade to 14.04 seems to have break something.

There's a problem while loading i965 driver: `undefined symbol: drm_intel_get_reset_stats`

Here's full trace, with glxinfo.

```
toilal@nas:~$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose glxinfo|grep renderer
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI3 capable
libGL: pci id for fd 4: 8086:0152, driver i965
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so: undefined symbol: drm_intel_get_reset_stats)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying ${ORIGIN}/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen ${ORIGIN}/dri/i965_dri.so failed (${ORIGIN}/dri/i965_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/dri/i965_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: driver does not expose __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast(): /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/swrast_dri.so: undefined symbol: __driDriverGetExtensions_swrast
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/toilal/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/toilal/.drirc: No such file or directory.
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_query_renderer, 
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 256 bits)
```

Comment: I couldn't find any solution to this issue, and installed ubuntu again from scrach. It worked, but what a pain ...

Answer (score 0):

Ouch! Well, I wasn't on 14.04 back then, but a:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo reboot
```

would have fixed it too!